# asp:Button inside asp:hyperlink does not navigate to page in internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:button which is inside an asp:hyperlink.  When you click the button in firefox, it goes to the correct url specified by the asp:hyperlink, but if you click the button in internet explorer, it stays on the same page.  I am just using the PostBackUrl property on the button to resolve the issue, but here is an example of the code:

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="hyp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Page2.aspx">
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" /></asp:Hyperlink>
```

**Why does the above work in firefox, but not IE?**

Comment: I would say you really want to ask how to style an hyperlink as a button

Comment: I am styling the button, but my question is why does the above work in firefox, but not in IE.

Comment: Yes but you don't need the hyperlink and the button, it's overkill, use a single control that fits the purpose i.e. LinkButton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did is not very correct.

Just add the button and in its click handler do:

```
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

Alternatively you can write a line of javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Text" onclick="location='Page2.aspx'" />
```

Comment: Im just using the PostBackUrl property on the button which works fine.

Comment: PostBackUrl is another story but it should work too. There are just too many solutions to this problem.

Comment: Any idea why my code above would not work in IE, but in firefox.

Comment: Probably firefox considers the click on the button also for the hyperlink. Not sure though :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you are using a button inside a hyperlink?  Depending on the design you are trying to achive I would use just a Button or a LinkButton and then do a redirect after your logic in the codebehind

```
<asp:Button runat='server' id='button1' Text='Click Me' Click='button1_Click' />
<asp:LinkButton runat='server' id='linkbutton1' Text='Click Me'  Click='button1_Click' />
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // some logic
  Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
```

**Firefox vs Internet Explorer**

I suspect your having discrepencies between Firefox and Internet Explorer because of the way the events are bubbled/propogated between the browsers.  If you would like to cancel the propagation of the event, you would need to include a call to event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation() in your button click event handler (in javascript)?

Comment: Actually, I think I did this by accident, but now I am curious as to why it works in firefox, but not IE.  This may not be the best answer, but I am using a button because I am setting a CssClass on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is executing a postback on the same page. If I were you I would try and use a standard button in your HTML toolbox instead of an ASP.NET button.

Edit: I would more highly suggest eliminating your button control and styling your hyperlink appropriately, or eliminate both and use a hyperlinkbutton control instead and have its display properties set to display as a button.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `<asp:LinkButton CssClass="myButton" OnClick="Redirect" />` and then CSS to style it how you want it to look and the code-behind to handle the functionality.

```
protected void Redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do something
}
```

Three way seperation of presentation, markup and functionality is the way to go in my opinion

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing with the button, but I was just curious as to why it works in firefox and not in ie.